# Height TableView Cells: Alignment label spaces

Tags: uitableview, height, ios7, row

Guys can someone 'tell me why I can not align well the label in these cell? ... The space between the black and the yellow label should be the same but I can not figure out the exact point you want to change in the code ... Surely it is a trivial but I'm lost
[image]

This is the code I'm using

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    NSString *comment = [[self.objects objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] objectForKey:@"TITOLO"];
    CGFloat whidt =  220;
    UIFont *FONT = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
    NSAttributedString *attributedText =[[NSAttributedString alloc]  initWithString:comment  attributes:@  { NSFontAttributeName: FONT }];
    CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){whidt, MAXFLOAT}
                                               options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                               context:nil];
    CGSize size = rect.size;
    return size.height +50;
}


- (FFCustomListaEsamiCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {    
    FFCustomListaEsamiCell  *cell = (FFCustomListaEsamiCell * )[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];   

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[FFCustomListaEsamiCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];       
    }

NSString *text = [object objectForKey:@"TITOLO"];
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(220 , 20000.0f);
    UIFont *FONT = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
    CGSize size = [text boundingRectWithSize:constraint options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:FONT }context:nil].size;

    cell.FFTitoloEsameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(17,10, 240, MAX(size.height, 10.0)+10.0 );
    cell.FFTitoloEsameLabel.text = text;
    NSDateFormatter *FFDataFormattata = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [FFDataFormattata setDateFormat:FF_DATE_FORMATTER];
    cell.FFDataEsameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",[FFDataFormattata stringFromDate:[object objectForKey:FF_ESAMI_DATA_STRING]]];

    PFObject *rowObject = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    
    if([[rowObject objectForKey:FF_ESAMI_STATUS] boolValue])    {

        cell.last.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FFIMG_ClockTAG"];
    }
    else
    {

    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by removing the auto-layout and setting the blocks with the size inspector ... I think it's the best solution and that is not a problem especially ... I hope ...